# How to modify this recursive definition?

Tags: summation, factorial, recursion

Let a sequence be defined recursively ($y_0=1$):

$$y_n=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j}y_jc_{n-j}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{j!(n-1-j)!}y_jc_{n-j}$$

I would like the recursive definition for $z_n = y_n/\sqrt{n!}$. However, this doesn't work:

$$z_n=\frac{y_n}{\sqrt{n!}}\neq\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\sqrt{\frac{n!}{j!}}\frac{1}{n(n-1-j)!}z_jc_{n-j}$$

Why? What's the correct way to obtain a recursive definition for $z_n$?
How about for $w_n = y_n/n!$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sqrt{n!}z_n=y_n=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{j!(n-1-j)!}y_jc_{n-j}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{j!(n-1-j)!}\sqrt{j!}z_jc_{n-j},$$
so after dividing by $\sqrt{n!}$, 
$$z_n=\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{\sqrt{(n-1)!}}{\sqrt{j!}(n-1-j)!}z_jc_{n-j}.$$

$${n!}w_n=y_n=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{j!(n-1-j)!}y_jc_{n-j}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{j!(n-1-j)!}{j!}w_jc_{n-j},$$
so after dividing by ${n!}$, 
$$w_n=\frac1{ n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(n-1-j)!}w_jc_{n-j}.$$

Comment: my formula was correct, I had a mistake in my test... Thank you for confirming that I wasn't crazy XD